# Storing user progress despite database changes for a VLE

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I'm planning to build a VLE system in Laravel 5 and have previously worked with Moodle and built a small VLE in CakePHP. I'm able to build the logic for assigning users to courses, giving courses lessons and questions to lessons as well as storing user progress through a specific course. However my only issue which was out of scope from my original CakePHP VLE is how to handle a user who is part way through a course when the course is updated.

The easiest way I could see for the system to work would be to invalidate previous lesson completions if the lesson is updated and require the user to retake the lesson. Unless the course has been completed then the lesson would stay completed. However then I have the problem if the user having completed questions that might no longer exist.

Is there any standard way of handling data with potentially changing relationships? Or any advise for handing situations like this? The only way I can picture avoiding any issues is to store all the users questions answers and completed lessons as JSON then use that data to output to the user on the front end.

Comment: Why would the question no longer exists? Have you thought of using soft deleting?

Comment: The admins on the previous system I made liked to make some long questions, then after a while split the out into 2-3 smaller questions or rearrange them. And if a user took a very old version of the course they could have in theory remade a lot of content or deleted the lessons outright.

Comment: Could you provide the tables and models you intend to use for users, courses, lessons and questions?